# Execute Ldap query from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, ldap, etl

Currently I am bringing data from oracle through ssis using tns names, but i need to move to LDAP. 
Can anyone kindly walk me through the process. Not able to find much on that.

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Google "SSIS query Active Directoy" returns some useful results

Comment: I am trying to call a procedure. Created connection manager and data source. My query looks something simillar to this.
insert into tbl_tab1
select * from openquery ( server_name
,'

SELECT
substr("some_DATE",1,50),
FROM TABLE(DATAFEED('USER_ID','13-sep-2015',490,'FORM_FIELD'))
') query

Ideally it should have returned me some data but I am not getting anything here.

Comment: Can you try steps in this article (found on google) http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1293.processing-active-directory-information-in-ssis.aspx